# Ballot problem with ties

Tags: probability, self-study

In an election, candidate $A$ receives $n$ votes and candidate $B$ receives $m$ votes where $n>m$. The probability that $A$ is always ahead in the count of the votes is $\dfrac{n-m}{n+m}$. This is known as [Bertrand's ballot theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).

A variation is to allow for ties. So for $n\geq m$ what is $P(A\text{ is never behind})$?

Comment: It's OK to answer your own questions. However, it would be better if you would post your answer as a separate post (i.e. answer your own question) and then select that post as the correct answer.

Comment: Could you turn your question into an actual question, please? Then your answer is a response to the question you pose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that the answer is $\dfrac{n-m+1}{n+1}$ So my first thought is to use induction on $n+m$. Suppose $n+m=1$ Since $n\geq m$, that means $n=1$ and $m=0$. Probability that candidate $A$ is never behind is $1$ since he has the only vote. so $$P(A\text{ is never behind}) = 1 = \dfrac{1-0+1}{1+1} = \dfrac{1}{1} $$

We will use the notation that $P_{n,m} = P(A\text{ is never behind})$ when $A$ has $n$ vote and $B$ has $m$ votes. Suppose the statement is true for $n+m=k-1$ we will prove it is true for $n+m=k$. We begin by conditioning on the result of the last vote. Either $A$ gets the last vote with probability $\dfrac{n}{n+m}$ or $B$ gets the last vote with probability $\dfrac{m}{n+m}$ So

$\begin{align*} P_{n,m} &= P_{n-1,m}\dfrac{n}{n+m} + P_{n,m-1}\dfrac{m}{n+m}\\
&= \dfrac{(n-1)-m+1}{(n-1)+1}\dfrac{n}{n+m} + \dfrac{n-(m-1)+1}{n+1}\dfrac{m}{n+m}\\
&= \dfrac{n-m+1}{n+1}\end{align*}$